# Retain white space in JSON keys

Tags: scala, gson

White Space in scala keys are not retained

```
case class c1(
  state :String,
  `Card No`:String
)
```

Request payload

```
{
  "state": "HH",
  "Card No": "c1234",
  "xxxx": "xxxx"
}
```

When used that case class in code after converting from gson to Json
it becomes

```
{"state":"HH","Card$u0020No":"c1234","xxx":"xxx"}
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried out `gson` for JSON processing. I use Play JSON `play.api.libs.json` framework.

The below works in play JSON:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class MyClass(State: String, `Card No`: String)

// Play can convert any case class into a JsValue, using macros.
// you will need an implicit `Writes` for `MyClass`
implicit private val MyClassWrites = Json.writes[MyClass]

val myobj = MyClass(State = "Bangalore", `Card No` = "Bl@#1234")

val json = Json.toJson(myobj)

println(json)
```

Gives the below JSON:

```
{"State":"Bangalore","Card No":"Bl@#1234"}
```

Will update this once I checkout gson lib.

**Update: With Gson**

I would like you not having backquotes to define case class values, rather have it in the standard format - maybe as camel cases. This would help keep the code cleaner. 
Like below:

```
case class MyClassA (state: String, cardNo: String)
```

and use the gson `FieldNamingPolicy` to get the right formatting while building the JSON.
You can create a gson builder and do something like this

```
val status = MyClassA(State = "Bangalore", cardNo = "Bl@#1234")

val gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE_WITH_SPACES)
    .setPrettyPrinting().create()

println(gson.toJson(status))
```

`FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE_WITH_SPACES` will ensure that the first letter of the field name is capitalized when serialized to its JSON form and the words will be separated by a space.

above will produce the below JSON.

```
{
  "State": "Bangalore",
  "Card No": "Bl@#1234"
}
```

Also, you can use `@SerializedName` annotation on any field name to specify the serialized name.

**Using annotation**
Using the `SerializedName` as below:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder._

case class MyClassA (
    State: String, 
    @(SerializedName @scala.annotation.meta.field)("card no")
    cardNo: String
    )

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val status = MyClassA(State = "Bangalore", CARD = "Bl@#1234")
    val gson = new GsonBuilder()
      .setPrettyPrinting().create()

    println(gson.toJson(status))
  }
}
```

UPD: below is the library dependency I am using:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.6"
```

You need to use the meta-annotations in `scala.annotation.meta`. Refer this [git issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8975?orig=1)

Comment: Thank you.        When we use FieldNamingPolicy - IDENTITY , it should use the same name as we have given right?              Because we have keys as  Card NO, Card Data and CARD Data.

Comment: I need to use it in Scala  with @SerializedName for case class .   So                      case class                                                                                                                  
                 case class  C1( "State": String,@SerializedName ("Card No)    'Card No'  : String )

Comment: @Ria Updated the answer with the usage of annotation. Please do accept the answer if it solves the problem :)

Comment: Its not working in scala.                                                                                           <none> cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type <notype>
[error]                         @(SerializedName @scala.annotation.meta.field)("card no")

Comment: That strange are you importing the right packages? @Ria I am adding the complete snippet above with the library dependencies